# What is the best way to express "wishmaker" in Latin?

Tags: neologism

How would one express "wishmaker" in Latin?

My first thought was something like *factor optatorum* maker of wishes, but I'm wonder if there's another way to express it. It can be a phrase or a compound word.

Comment: As in, "one who wishes for things" (via what "make a wish" means in English)?

Comment: @Adam: A "wishmaker" is clearly a dreamer, in Latin, "somniator" (m), which also means, "one who puts faith in dreams".

Comment: @Draconis Good question! I'd be interested to see both "one who wishes for things" and also "one who makes wishes come true." It's okay if these are separate words, but it would be interesting if that ambiguity could be preserved.